# How do I sort a specific column (a - z) when I have merged cells that affect a portion of that column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to sort a specific column in Google sheets alphabetically, and have come across the following problem.

When I select the column that I would like to sort, an error message stating

> "You can't sort a range containing vertical merges. There is a vertical merge at `A1:S3`."

This is because I merged those rows and columns so that I could have a Heading for my sheet for when I print it out.

I've entered multiple versions of my question into a Google search and have found nothing that specifically relates to my problem. I realize that a simple fix for this would to simply delete that particular range of rows & columns when I am doing my sorting, but I was hoping that there might be a way to simply exclude that range so that I do not have to do the extra steps of deleting and reentering my 'Heading.'

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and do [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Probably, just add empty row A4:S4 just to be header for filter zone and shrink it.